# Why does Stage in JavaFX changes size when I use setScene() for the first time

Tags: java, user-interface, model-view-controller, javafx, controller

The problem is that Stage in JavaFX changes its size when I use setScene() in my button controller for the first time. For the second, third and other times everything is OK.
That's the controllers code:

```
Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
Parent profileParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../FXML/Profile.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(profileParent);
stage.setScene(scene);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the line `stage.sizeToScene();` after `stage.setScene(scene);`.